# How to scroll to top on button click in Telerik Appbuilder

Tags: jquery, cordova, kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-appbuilder

I want to scroll the page to top on the button click, I used jquery `.scrollTop` but it is not working.

Is there any other method to scroll the page in Telerik Appbuilder

Comment: Ok, have you tried with $('html,body').scrollTop(0);

Comment: Yes, It is not working..

Comment: Can you post the button's HTML and the jquery?